# Viewcell XAML + CS throws Build action 'Page' is not supported error

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I am trying to link my XAML ViewCell with the c# counterpart and use it with listview.
WeatherCell.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ViewCell  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Name="cell"
             x:Class="UI.WeatherCell">

  <ViewCell.View>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="10">

      <Label Text="WeatherCell"
             x:Name="TempLabel"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Center" />

      <Label Text="WeatherCell"
             x:Name="LocationLabel"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Center" />

    </StackLayout>
  </ViewCell.View>

</ViewCell >
```

WeatherCell.cs

```
namespace UI
{
    public partial class WeatherCell : ViewCell
    {
        public WeatherCell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Referred in MainPage.cs as follows

```
this.WeatherListView.ItemsSource = Weather.Weather.DataFactory.genForecast();
this.WeatherListView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(WeatherCell));
```

While building I get error as

```
'Page' is not supported by the specific combination of the project's targets. \WeatherCell.xaml.
```

My guesss was ***x:Class="UI.WeatherCell"*** will link both the xaml and cs. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing build action for WeatherCell.xaml fixed the problem.

it has to be set to `EmbeddedResource`

Build Action property can be found in file properties context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click the xaml file and click Properties.
Under Properties select `Embedded Resource`.
Rebuild your project.